# Trouble adding message.framework and messages module

Tags: swift, xcode, imessage

I am new to Mac development and am using xCode 14 to create a commandline project in swift. I need to use some functions in the messages.framework for iMessage stuff. I went to Build Phases and tried to add the framework with "Link Binary With Libraries" but the framework wasn't listed. So I did the "add other" dropdown and chose "add files" and navigated to "/System/Library/Frameworks/Messages.framework/" but even after I instantiated Messages() but it still says module not found.

How do I sucessfully add that framework to my xcode project so that I can use Messages()?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/, take a look at what OS’s are supported.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson , after messing with this several time, it appears you are on to something. Even if the app is supposed to include ios, if it has the MacOs with it, it does not seem to want to comply

Comment: The app can not support iOS if it is a command line tool